# Soundcloud iOS SDK - is there a signup view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soundcloud

I'm working on an iOS that is using the following SoundCloud library version from cocoapods:
pod 'CocoaSoundCloudAPI', '1.0.2'
pod 'CocoaSoundCloudUI', '1.0.9'

I've been successful in implementing the ability to login to SoundCloud using SCLoginViewController. I'd also like to give the user the ability to signup to SoundCloud, but I haven't had much luck finding an appropriate view controller in their iOS SDK, nor finding any other appropriate way to give the user the ability to create a SoundCloud account.

Does anyone know if it's possible to let a user signup for a SoundCloud account in an iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

Since SoundCloud decided not to maintain anymore this library I created my own one, maybe it could helps you. One of the request I've already implemented is login using an internal webview where the user can signup as well.

[image: SoundCloud internal webview to login and signup]

[ABMSoundCloudAPI on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)

Comment: Hello Andres,

Thanks for your answer. I've run into a cocoapods dependency issue:
- `AFNetworking (~> 2.5)` required by `ABMSoundCloudAPI (0.1.0)`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.24.0)`

As you can see, I use restkit, which requires an older/incompatible version of AFNetworking than your ABMSoundCloudAPI. Any tips on how to resolve this incompatibility? I'd really like to give your library a try.

Comment: Investigating a little bit I found RestKit has a branch for AFNetworking 2.0 (experimental) but it doesn't works :(. I am afraid the only way to accomplish that is to migrate the version of AFNetworking I am using to 1.x.x, but I am using 2.x.x in my app. So maybe you can fork it and replace every call, it shouldn't be a lot of work.

Comment: I was just attempting to use their pork to AFNetworking 2.0 branch as well, I might be able to make my own forks of a few of their pods, but it's likely easier just to fork and modify your project like you suggested. - I noticed your SoundCloudLoginWebViewController.m had an unnecessary import statement on line 10 (#import "SoundCloudPort.h"), and without it that file doesn't depend on any other files. Do you think there would be any issue if I tried using just the SoundCloudLoginWebViewController.m and .h in my project, thereby avoiding the AFNetworking dependency altogether?

Comment: Wow, nice catch! Yes, definitely, if you only need login/signup feature you can use only that class. Don't forget to copy `SoundCloudLogin.storyboard` as well ;)

Comment: I've implemented your login vc into my app, and the user can successfully login, which passes me back a code. The last thing I need to do is perform a follow request for this user I now have logged in. I've already implemented sending a follow request with the CocoaSoundCloudAPI using SCRequest, and if I wanted to continue using that I would need a way to turn the code your library passes back into an SCAccount (more coming in next comment).

Comment: I've been going through their SDK to see if that is possible, and I haven't found anything helpful. Do you know if it's possible to turn the code your library passed back into an SCAccount instance? If not, do you know how to perform a follow request starting using said code? I see in your code, you request an auth token using that code, is that my next step?